# Regex to detect html tags and replace just some

Tags: java, regex

Having a XML like this:

```
<Abc>
    <Bcd>C</Bcd>
    <Def>E</Def>
    <Fgh>G</Fgh>
</Abc>
```

Which would be the correct Java RegEx to change it to the following?

```
-Abc-
    -Bcd-Cde-/Bcd-
    <Def>E</Def>
    <Fgh>G</Fgh>
-/Abc-
```

I made it to:

```
myString.replaceAll("\\<(.*?)\\>","-$1-");
```

but I'm not able to do the proper exclusions, so that only some tags are changed.

**Update:** Using the negation of Pshemo's answer did the trick:

```
myString.replaceAll("\\<?!(KWD|COM|PLN|PUN|TYP|STR)\\>","&lt;$1&gt;")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex on HTML code is not good idea as pointed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) but if you really want to complicate your life then you can use OR `|` operator like

```
String yourData = "<Abc>\n" 
                + "    <Bcd>C</Bcd>\n"
                + "    <Def>E</Def>\n" 
                + "    <Fgh>G</Fgh>\n" 
                + "</Abc>";
System.out.println(yourData.replaceAll("</?(Abc|Bcd)>", "-$1-"));
```

output:

```
-Abc-
    -Bcd-C-Bcd-
    <Def>E</Def>
    <Fgh>G</Fgh>
-Abc-
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid this bad practice, but I need to do it. Jsoup doesn't work properly. For tags like <tag><b><tag> it detects <b> as tag and not as text, so i need to replace bracket with the entities, but only for the tags i don't need (I know precisely the ones i need). This made the trick, but I used ?! because i want to replace all but some. The pattern i used is: replaceAll("\\<?!(KWD|COM|PLN|PUN|TYP|STR)\\>","&lt;$1&gt;")

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
"\\<[AB]\\>"
```

for your regular expression.  It will find < then A or B then >.  For more information see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

To extend it even further for full sets of characters you can use the following format.

```
public class RegexString
{
    private static String myString = "<Abc>\n" 
            + "    <Bcd>C</Bcd>\n"
            + "    <Def>E</Def>\n" 
            + "    <Fgh>G</Fgh>\n" 
            + "</Abc>";
    private static final String HTML_TAGS = "/?(Abc|Bcd)";
    private static final String FULL_REGEX = "<" + HTML_TAGS + ">";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
          System.out.println(myString.replaceAll(FULL_REGEX, "-$1-"));
    }
}
```

Comment: A can even be a word, not just a letter

Comment: Sorry, I used just letters to simplify :)